# Making an image "fit to screen" in pygame?

Tags: python, image, user-interface, pygame

So basically I'm using pygame in a project where I'm designing a comic book viewer. I've been able to load the image in, display it, modify it's dimensions, but haven't been able to fit it to the window as it resizes.

So far I just have the image stretched across the canvas, when I resize, it stays in place and everything looks "glitchy". Here is my source: https://github.com/averyre/ComicSnake/blob/master/comicsnake.py

Specifically, this block:

```
## The GUI loop.
while 1:
    screenWidth, screenHeight = screen.get_size();
    pygame.event.wait()
    screen.fill(black)
    page = pygame.transform.scale(page,[screenWidth, screenHeight]);
    screen.blit(page, pagerect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`screen` is `Surface` (buffer in memory) which is created at start and doesn't change size - it is not window which you resize.

When you resize window then it is sends event `VIDEORESIZE` which has fields `event.size`, `event.w`, `event.h` and it is window's size after resize.

See doc: [event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)

Example code from pygame.org's wiki: [WindowResizing](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/WindowResizing?parent=CookBook).
It shows how to use `VIDEORESIZE` to resize `screen` and image.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500), HWSURFACE|DOUBLEBUF|RESIZABLE)
pic = pygame.image.load("example.png") #You need an example picture in the same folder as this file!
screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(pic, (500,500)), (0,0))
pygame.display.flip()

while True:
    pygame.event.pump()
    event = pygame.event.wait()
    if event.type == QUIT: 
        pygame.display.quit()
    elif event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode(event.dict['size'], HWSURFACE|DOUBLEBUF|RESIZABLE)
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(pic, event.dict['size']), (0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm having some trouble integrating this into my code. I understand the "quit" event type and how it functions but I can't manage to get my image to resize based on the window. Any attempts to recreate something similar and I have the same issue.

Comment: `QUIT` event is not important - you have to use `VIDEORESIZE` to get window size and recreate `screen` and resize image. You can copy all code from my `while True`  to your `while`loop with different variables.